# Axiomatization of the equational theory of ideals in a commutative ring

Tags: commutative-algebra

Is there a known  axiomatization of the equational theory of ideal operations in a commutative ring? I have in mind the following: Consider a language with operations for ideal intersection, product, sum and quotient, and constant symbols for the zero-ideal and for the ring itself as an ideal.  Questions:

1. Is there a finite set of equations using the preceeding operations and any number of variables which axiomatize, in the sense of first order logic, the set of ideal identities that hold in every commutative ring?
2. If the answer to Question 1 is "no", then is there at least some known effective axiomatization that sheds some light on the equational theory?

Comment: I am confused about the part about quotient, since taking the quotient of two ideals does not result in an ideal.

Comment: Jason, if I and J are ideals in a ring R, then the quotient I:J is defined to be the set of all x in R such that xJ is a subset of I.

Comment: Ah, okay.  For some reason I am familiar with I:J but I never had a word for it.  This is an interesting question.